# Django login form

Tags: python, django

I'm a novice to django, altough I have some experience using python. I'm currently learning django, but when I try to use the included login system, I get the following error:

```
Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/login.html (File does not exist)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/registration/login.html (File does not exist)
```

Relevant code from views.py:

```
@login_required
def userPage(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello User!")
```

I am using django 1.6.1 and python 2.7.5 on Fedora 20. I have already tried reinstalling django. In the folders from the error message are other templates. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to provide the urls (project/urls.py)

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout

url(
    regex=r'^login/$', 
    view=login, 
    kwargs={'template_name': 'login.html'}, 
    name='login'
),
url(
    regex=r'^logout/$', 
    view=logout, 
    kwargs={'next_page': '/'}, 
    name='logout'
),
```

and the template `login.html` (something like that)

```
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <label>{{ field.label }}</label>
        {% if field.errors %}
            {{ field.errors }}
        {% endif %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    <input class="button small" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `login.html` needs to be inside a folder named registration (which needs to reside in a directory listed in TEMPLATE_DIRS)

Comment: That solved it! The next thing I had to do was setting LOGIN_URL in settings.py [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#login-url)

Answer (score 5):

Check the [documentation about authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views):

> It’s your responsibility to provide the html for the login template

The documentation provides a sample template.